# setting fixed width with 100% height of the parent

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, I want to set the height of `left` and `right` 100% of the `parent` element. In addition, the `left` div has fixed width. The `right` should use all of the remaining width.

I think because of using `display: flex;` in the parents div, the width of the `left` div doesn't stay constant. How can I set fixed width for it and allocate all of the remaining space to the right.

**Edit:** the `calc(100-52px)` is the height of the `parent`. The question is only about setting fixed width of 100px to the left so that it doesn't change on resizing the window.

[image]

Here's what I'm trying:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 52px);
  
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;      
  
}

.right {    
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 
     <div class="left">the width should be fixed, not flexible</div>  
     <div class="right">width should be all of the remaining</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: It works how you described for me...

Comment: do you want right to be at 52px from the right edge ? else i do not see what the question is about. it works fine.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus no, sorry ignore that. that is the parent height. Question is only about setting the `left`a fixed width of 100. Seems like because of the `display: flex` it changes on the resizing window.

Comment: okay, then .left would need : flex:0 0 100px; :) and right  flex-grow:1; to meet the flex rules/behavior ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100% - 100px)` or `flex: 1` for the right div.

Percentage values are calculated from the parent element, therefore you need to extract static values from 100% to get the remaining area.

But as you are already using a flex container here, you can just set flex: 1, which is the shorthand for flex-grow: 1, that will allow your container to take all the extra space in the parent container, since no other items are available.

Answer (score 2):

parent { display: -webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap; }

.parent > [class*='col-'] { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }

Answer (score 1):

Add a `flex` declaration to the `.left` selector:

```css
flex: 0 0 100px;
```

**`flex`** syntax:

```
none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]
```

So this declaration is stating: "don't grow, don't shrink, define the initial size as 100px"

Read more: [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (MDN)

Answer (score 1):

If right is to stand 52px away from the far right, then a margin will do . Please clarify your question.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 52px);
}

.left {
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="left">the width should be fixed, not flexible</div>
  <div class="right">width should be all of the remaining</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `flex: 0 0 100px;` on your `.left` div (you can remove `width: 100px`) if you want it to be a constant 100px - so no growing or shrinking.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 52px);
  
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: yellow;      
  
}

.right {    
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 
     <div class="left">the width should be fixed, not flexible</div>  
     <div class="right">width should be all of the remaining</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps you, comment if you need any changes

[stackblits link for 1 fixed width, 1 relative column](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3r66mg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)